# $Show: a\in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow 6\mid a^3 -a$

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers

$Show: a\in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow 6\mid a^3 -a$

My attempt:

NTS: $6\mid a^3 -a$, so $(2\mid a^3 -a) \land (3\mid a^3 -a)$

Assume that $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, therefore I have 2 cases:

1. a is even $\Rightarrow a=2k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$
2. a is odd $\Rightarrow a=2k+1, k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Therefore in case 1: $a^3-a=(2k)^3-2k=8k^3-2k$

and in case 2: $a^3-a=(2k+1)^3-(2k+1)=8k^3+2k$

And it led me to a blind alley. I can only factor 2 out of the expressions but there's no way to factor 3 out, so $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Is there a way to show that using direct proof and the assumption?

I also tried to factor the $a^3-a=(a-1)(a)(a+1)$ but it isn't telling me much either.

Comment: $a^3\equiv a\pmod3$ by  Fermat's little theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a-1,a,a+1$ are three consecutive integers, so at least one of them must be even and one of them must be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Would you accept this answer if you were lets say grading an exam sheet?: $a^3-a=(a-1)(a)(a+1)$ are three consecutive integers, so one of them must be divisible by 3 and one must be even, therefore product of the integers must be divisible by 6, since $6\mid a^3 -a, \iff (2\mid a^3 -a) \land (3\mid a^3 -a)$

Comment: @Jakub Yes, I would.

Answer (score 2):

At least one of the factors $a, a-1,a+1$ must be divisible by $3$ and also by $2$ and since gcd$(2,3) = 1$, the product divisible by $2\cdot 3 = 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ $\in\mathbb {Z}$.

Given:
           $a^{3}-a=a(a-1)(a+1)$

For $a$ even, then 2 | $a$. If $a$ is odd, clearly we got that $a + 1$ or $a - 1$ is even.
So for a $\in\mathbb {Z}$, 2 | $a^{3}-a$.

Since gdc(2,3)=1, we need to show  $3$| $a^{3}-a$.

For a $\in\mathbb {Z}$, $a$ can be written in one of the following forms $3k_{0}$,   $3k_{1}+1$,  $3k_{2}+2$, with $  k_{0}$,$k_{1}$,$k_{2}$ $\in$ $\mathbb {Z}$.

Using this forms for $a$ and the above factorization the result follows.